# How to debug my Ajax/jQuery app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying some things regarding Ajax, Jquery and PHP.

My JavaScript code (the pop.php is located correctly)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.nameclick').click(function()) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                typ: "POST"
                url: "/pop.php"
                data: {id=$(this).data("formid")}
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                } else {
                    alert("test");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Part of my html/php code in the same page (this code works fine to print out the table I am looking for):

```
        <table class="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Servicenummer</th>
                    <th>Kund</th>
                    <th>Uppgift</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Inlämnad</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $no     = 1;
            $total  = 0;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td><div id="clickMe">'.$row['service'].'</div></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="nameclick" data-formid="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></td>
                        <td>'.$row['Drakt1'].'<br>'.$row['Drakt2'].'<br>'.$row['Drakt3'].'<br>'.$row['Drakt4'].'<br>'.$row['Drakt5'].'<br>'.$row['Drakt6'].'<br>'.$row['reg1'].'<br>'.$row['flaska1'].'<br>'.$row['dator1'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['Service_Status'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                $no++;
            }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And my pop.php:

```
        <?php
        require 'connection.php';
        $conn           = Connect();
        $name           = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $email          = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $telephone      = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);

        $sql = 'SELECT name, email, telephone FROM Service_Form WHERE id = "10"';

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (!$query) {
            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        ?>

            <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                {
                        echo $row['name'];
                        echo $row['email'];
                        echo $row['telephone'];
                }
            ?>
```

At the moment when I click my link in my normal page I don't get anything, no alerts at all, but my pop.php prints out the values correctly, I hope... I know I have to change my id="10" to something but i am not certain to what, could it be formid?

What am I doing wrong here?

What I want:

- a table with the values below from a table in the database
- when I click the name in the table it should show an alert (or something similar) that shows the name, email and telephone number (these are stored as well in the database table but not on the website table).

Comment: This `data: {id=$(this).data("formid")}` is invalid syntax, try `data: {id:$(this).data("formid")}`

Comment: `$('.nameclick').click(function()) {
            ev.preventDefault();` - you forgot to define `ev`, so it won't stop the normal behaviour of the link. `$('.nameclick').click(function(ev)) {
            ev.preventDefault(); ` would be correct. It's not the root of the issue, but worth noting. It might be causing a JS error - check your browser's console in the developer tools.

Comment: also it's unclear why pop.php is trying to read POST values called name, email, telephone, because your ajax does not pass any of those values to it. Only ID is passed as an input (and as the comment above notes, it's not passed correctly). You should be looking for $_POST["id"] and including that in your query instead of "10" if you want to use that as the variable to determine the query output.

Comment: @ADyson yes I want to use $_POST["id"] instead of 10. That is good, thank you :).

I want to send the ID and get name, email and telephone back basically :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ajax function is having some errors

so use this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.nameclick').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data("formid");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pop.php",
            data: {
                  "id":id
                 },
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            },
            error:function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `alert(error);` is a bit pointless, since `error` is quite quite a complex jquery XHR object, the output will be meaningless. It should report some of the specific fields, if required. Also, `ev` is not defined at the start of the function. Otherwise, this should work better than the OP code.

Comment: Thank you @Exprator I have tried it. It seems that the problem is in the preventDefault as it continues to open the link instead...

Comment: try it now @PeterP

Comment: @exprator I have now fixed the ajax code and I know that it is being sent to the pop.php but pop.php doesnt return any values... I have chanched the pop.php slightly so that I know that it gets the value from the ajax code but it doesnt return the axtual name, telehone and email. What do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am editing your jquery part please try

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.nameclick').click(function(ev)) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    typ: "POST"
                    url: "/pop.php"
                    data: {id:$(this).attr("data-formid")}
                    success: function(result){
                       if(result){
                            alert(result);
                       } else {
                        alert("test");
                       }
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `ev` is not defined at the start of the function.